# Hadoop: unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, hadoop

Before you read my question, you should know that it's not a duplicate to all other similar questions on Stackoverflow that I already read!

I've developed (and built and compiled) a Hadoop program on `Windows 10` (development machine) using Eclipse. The program reads WARC files and rewrite them in JSON format. It uses [these classes to override the Writable format](http://www.lemurproject.org/clueweb09/workingWithWARCFiles.php#Classes_for_Hadoop):

```
WarcFileInputFormat.java
WarcFileRecordReader.java
WritableWarcRecord.java
```

I added `hadoop- 2.6.0` jars files to my project.
This is the java version of **development machine**:

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I tested my code on `Ubuntu 14` machine (testing machine) and it just worked perfectly. this machine has `hadoop- 2.6.0`:

```
Hadoop 2.6.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 18e43357c8f927c0695f1e9522859d6a
This command was run using /home/username/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
```

This is the java version of **testing machine**:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I moved to a CentOS oracle server and ran my program. This server has the **same java version as my development machine**:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

and it had this Hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.13.1
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r 0061e3eb8ab164e415630bca11d299a7c2ec74fd
Compiled by jenkins on 2017-11-09T16:37Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 16d5272b34af2d8a4b4b7ee8f7c4cbe
This command was run using /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.1-1.cdh5.13.1.p0.2/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.13.1.jar
```

On this server I got the following error for each job:

```
18/02/23 11:59:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1517308433710_0012_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error: data/warc/WarcFileInputFormat : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

**Here are the things I tried and they didn't work**:

1. Adding the WARC readers' classes to my project as classes not as a jar to build them using the correct java version.
2. Changing Hadoop jar files version from `hadoop- 2.6.0` to `hadoop- 2.6.0-cdh5.13.1`
3. Using `mapred` instead of `mapreduce` as the reader classes are using `mapred`

I'm not sure what exactly causes this issue especially that it points to the class WarcFileInputFormat.java that I didn't write but added to my project from the link I provided above. What surprised me is that the program worked perfectly on `Ubuntu` machine that has a lower java version, but didn't work on the `CentOS` server that has the same java version as the `Windows` development machine!

Any hints?

Comment: The is no magic, the message comes from old JVM. Try `sudo alternatives --display java` or plain `find` to search for `java` actually used to execute jobs. Maybe check if `ps aux |grep java` includes unexpected path to java.

Comment: I have no other version of java except JAVA8 `$ sudo alternatives --display java` gives 
`java - status is manual.
 link currently points to /opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java
/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java - priority 2
Current best version is /opt/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `Cloudera` uses a lower version of JAVA:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java
```

Comment: How did you solve it? Did you install java-7 and remove your previous version or somehow you upgraded Cloudera java version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message as yours, it occurred to me when I was implementing a Hive UDF.

I saw your answer and I tried Java 1.7 instead of 1.8 to build the JAR file of the UDF, and it worked.

I was using Cloudera Quickstart VM and it has JAVA_HOME set to Java 1.7